# How to show specific content on a separate page using Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, tags, view, content-type

1- i have menu links **HOME | Property**(links to property content type) | **NEWS**.

2- In every News there are tags which reference to the property.

3- I want to link "NEWS" menu item to a separate page which should display only the news list which contains the tags for the property.

**Example**

i am on a property page say "Property XYZ", so there is a menu item "NEWS", when i click this menu item, a new page opens and this page is showing news which contain the Tag "Property XYZ" in them.

How to do this thing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Views module to create a new View of nodes of type News, with a display of type Page (since you want the News listing to be a separate page).

Then you can add a Contextual Filter to the View, which is the way you can pass the Property as a parameter to filter to only News with that Property as a tag. You do this by adding the News field containing the tags as Contextual Filter for the view.

At this point you'll have a view page with something like 'news/%' as a path (where % is a placeholder for the Property parameter), so then you only need to use the appropriate substitution for it in each Property page for the News link on that page (like make it link to 'news/propertyxyz' while on PropertyXYZ page).

If the menu containing the NEWS menu item is outside of the scope of the Property page (like in the case of the site main menu or something like that) then you can use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7.x to alter the path, getting the corresponding Property object (and any value you need to pass as parameter) through https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7.x